# Copy content from one workbook to another, pasting as special

Tags: excel, vba

My current vba code copies data from one sheet of my current and creates a new workbook with the data from that sheet.

```
Sub copying_data()

Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
Dim FName As String


FName = FilePath & "Summary_Output_" & _
        Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AA_New").Copy
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 110
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 120
Set NewBook = ActiveWorkbook
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FName

End Sub
```

This is currently working fine, but when it pastes the data it links it to the old sheet, instead I want it to paste the data as value but keeping the same formatting, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just small variations to Scott's answer which is perfectly valid.

1. Variable names conventions
2. Defining the file name in a different variable to use it in other steps
3. Windows adjustments you had in your code

---

```
Public Sub copying_data()

    Dim newBook As Workbook

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fileFullPath As String

    ' Build the path
    filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

    fileName = "Summary_Output_" & _
            Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"

    fileFullPath = filePath & fileName

    ' Add a new workbook
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

    ' Save it with the path built
    newBook.SaveAs fileFullPath

    ' Copy the sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AA_New").Copy Before:=Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(1)

    ' Copy/paste values
    newBook.Sheets("AA_New").UsedRange.Copy
    newBook.Sheets("AA_New").UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    newBook.Sheets("AA_New").UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    ' Adjust the window
    Windows(fileName).DisplayGridlines = False
    Windows(fileName).Zoom = 110
    Windows(fileName).Zoom = 120

End Sub
```

Comment: This is really good, thanks for taking the time to include all of my specifications

Comment: One thing: Do you know why the colors of my series in my chart change, when the chart is copied across?

Comment: It's the theme. You'd need to apply the same theme to the new file.

Answer (score 2):

Add the file first then copy and paste special the values and formatting into the new sheet:

```
Sub copying_data()

    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

    Dim FName As String
    FName = FilePath & "Summary_Output_" & _
            Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"

    Dim swb As Workbook
    Set swb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim twb As Workbook
    Set twb = Workbooks.Add

    swb.Worksheets("AA_New").UsedRange.Copy

    With twb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End With

    twb.Worksheets(1).Name = "AA_New"
    twb.SaveAs Filename:=FName
End Sub
```